# aspnet _membership MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey is returning an integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm using the aspnet_membership with an MVC4 website project. This is just for a quick demo, it doesn't need to be robust yet.  I haven't defined roles yet, so simply registering should provide access to the various pages.

I need to get the UserId from the User table and I'm using the recommended method **Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey**. However, ProviderUserKey appears to have a value of '2' which is not castable to a Guid. I'm guessing that I haven't set up something in the aspnet_membership that I need to be able to do this.  What do I need to do or configure to get a Guid value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC4 uses SimpleMembership rather than the old SqlMembership.  SimpleMembership, by default uses an integer identity key for the users table.  If you want a Guid, then you would need to change the way SimpleMembership works or you could go back to using the old SqlMembership.